# gradle commandline parameters not passing to child tasks

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, command-line-arguments

Am unable to use command line properties in the tasks called from the task actually executed from commandline. Please suggest what am I missing?

*build.gradle* snippet:

```
task createZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'copyContentToZip') {
    ext {
        buildNumber = project.hasProperty('buildNumber') ? project.property('buildNumber') : 'default'
        stagingDestPath= project.hasProperty('stagingDestPath') ? project.property('stagingDestPath') : 'C:/Sites/Project/releases/'
    }
    from tempContainerDir + projName 
    baseName projName +'-'+buildVersion+ '-'+ buildNumber
    destinationDir file(stagingDestPath)

}

task cleanBuildPublish(type: GradleBuild) {
    description 'Creates the clean build of oms.zip.'

    ext {
        buildNumber = project.hasProperty('buildNumber') ? project.property('buildNumber') : 'default'
        stagingDestPath= project.hasProperty('stagingDestPath') ? project.property('stagingDestPath') : 'C:/Sites/Project/releases/'
    }
     tasks = ['collectAllDependencies', 'createZip']
}
```

*gradle.properties:*

```
projName = test
buildVersion = 578
tempContainerDir = releases/tmp/
```

***Command:*** gradlew -PbuildNumber=2088  -PstagingDestPath=C:/Sites/Project  cleanBuildPublish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can forward the project properties of your main build to the nested build:

```
task cleanBuildPublish(type: GradleBuild) {
    description 'Creates the clean build of oms.zip.'

    //forward projectProperties
    startParameter.projectProperties = project.gradle.startParameter.projectProperties

    ext {
        buildNumber = project.hasProperty('buildNumber') ? project.property('buildNumber') : 'default'
        stagingDestPath= project.hasProperty('stagingDestPath') ? project.property('stagingDestPath') : 'C:/Sites/Project/releases/'
    }
    tasks = ['collectAllDependencies', 'createZip']
}
```